# React validations not working with socket

Tags: reactjs, sockets, state

so I receive data through socket from backend and then I push the data (item) to an array, but If a variable is true (means its paused) I dont want to push the item to the array.

```
    const [sales, setSales] = useState([])
    const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);
    const handlePush = (dt) => {
        if(paused) return;
            let data = dt.itemListed.data
            let obj = {
                name: dt.itemListed.data.item.metadata.name,
                data
            }
            if (sales.findIndex(i => i.name === dt.itemListed.data.item.metadata.name) > 0) return;
            if (sales.length >= 10) sales.pop();
            setSales(prevState => [obj, ...prevState])
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("itemListed", (dt) => {
            handlePush(dt);
        })
    }, [socket])
```

The variable paused is set to true, Im already debugging it and I have also a text displaying on the screen saying if its paused or not. Also, the code where I check if the array size is 10 is also not working.

The code was working fine, but then I changed into socket.io-client lib, and it stopped working.

What I think is happening is that the useEffect is being "read" only once and it is ignoring the futures validations and it keeps just pushing the items.

What can I do?

Comment: To be clear, is the issue the function pause value is always false, so it would keep pushing items even when paused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your issue

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("itemListed", (dt) => {
        handlePush(dt);
    })

    return () => {
        socket.off("itemListed") // cleanup
    };
}, [socket, handlePush])
```

Your useEffect is listening on a previous version of handlePush that uses the old `pause` value, so that's why it still able to push.

If you add the function `handlePush` as a dependency for useEffect it would re-run every time handlePush changes so you would have the latest function.

For performance, you should also utilize the [`useCallback()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook on the `handlePush()` function.